# request.GET() cannot fetch data from the given input. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, django

Thi is my html code:

```
<form action ="add">
    Enter 1st number = <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number = <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type ="submit">
</form>
```

This is the python code

```
def add(request):
    val1 = int(request.GET['num1'])
    val2 = int(request.GET['num2'])
    res = val1 + val2
```

This is the error:

"GET /add?num1=10&num2=20 HTTP/1.1" 200 297

Comment: That does not look like an error at all. In fact it clearly shows a status 200...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But the add function is not working. Its not showing the addition of two values in the result. Can you please explain why the answer is not showing?

Comment: why do you expect that here: you assigned it to `res`. But what did you do with `res`? Can you show what template your are rendering (or other HTTP response you are constructing)?

Comment: def add(request):
    val1 = int(request.GET['num1'])
    val2 = int(request.GET['num2'])
    res = val1 + val2
    return render(request,"result.html", {'Result':res})

This is the result.html:
Result:{{res}}

It only shows Result...But not showing the addition

Comment: you should render it with `{{ Result }}`.

Comment: Thanks. It's working

Comment: @travel Django is quite extensively documented, and has [a nice official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/) that explain all those things. May I kindly suggest you do this tutorial ? It will save you a _lot_ of time and pain...

Answer (score 0):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58009122/request-get-cannot-fetch-data-from-the-given-input-how-can-i-solve-this/58009358#comment102422790_58009122), your view looks like:

```
def add(request):
    val1 = int(request.GET['num1'])
    val2 = int(request.GET['num2'])
    res = val1 + val2
    return render(request,"result.html", {'Result': res})
```

This thus means that you passed your result `res` to the template through the name `Result`, *not* <s>`res`</s>.

In your template, you thus should render it as:

```
Result: {{ Result }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
val1=int(request.GET.get('number1')),
val2=int(request.GET.get('number2'))
```

I suggest you do go for this approach and change num1 to number1 I really don't know why but chance the name of num1 to number1 or any other, its working and change in your form name also

```py
input type="number" name="number1"
```